# Pivoting a DataFrame in Pandas for output to CSV

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

This is a simple question for which answer are surprisingly difficult to find online. Here's the situation:

```
>>> A
[('hey', 'you', 4), ('hey', 'not you', 5), ('not hey', 'you', 2), ('not hey', 'not you', 6)]
>>> A_p = pandas.DataFrame(A)
>>> A_p
         0        1  2
0      hey      you  4
1      hey  not you  5
2  not hey      you  2
3  not hey  not you  6
>>> B_p = A_p.pivot(0,1,2)
>>> B_p
1        not you  you
0                    
hey            5    4
not hey        6    2
```

This isn't quite what's suggested in the documentation for `pivot` -- there, it shows results without the 1 and 0 in the upper-left-hand corner. And that's what I'm looking for, a DataFrame object that prints as

```
         not you  you
hey            5    4
not hey        6    2
```

The problem is that the normal behavior results in a csv file whose first line is

```
0,not you,you
```

when I really want

```
not you, you
```

When the normal csv file (with the preceding "0,") reads into R, it doesn't properly set the column and row names from the frame object, resulting in painful manual manipulation to get it in the right format. Is there a way to get pivot to give me a DataFrame object without that additional information in the upper-left corner?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example including sample data? How are you writing the csv file? You might try write.csv(..., row.names=FALSE).

Comment: I believe this is a bug in pandas. I tried this on an older version of pandas and got the desired result.

Comment: to build on @tcash21 , it would be really helpful if you could convert the pandas output to either a list of lists or a list of dicts and then show the result of the conversion e.g. with `map(list, B_p)`.  (since whatever form of the csv writer you are using needs to work on an iterable anyways).

Answer (score 4):

Well, you have:

```
In [17]: B_p.to_csv(sys.stdout)
0,not you,you
hey,5.0,4.0
not hey,6.0,2.0

In [18]: B_p.to_csv(sys.stdout, index=False)
not you,you
5.0,4.0
6.0,2.0
```

But I assume you want the row names. Setting the index name to None (`B_p.index.name = None`) gives a leading comma:

```
In [20]: B_p.to_csv(sys.stdout)
,not you,you
hey,5.0,4.0
not hey,6.0,2.0
```

This roughly matches (ignoring quoted strings) what R writes in `write.csv` when `row.names=TRUE`:

```
"","a","b"
"foo",0.720538259472741,-0.848304940318957
"bar",-0.64266667412325,-0.442441171401282
"baz",-0.419181615269841,-0.658545964124229
"qux",0.881124313748992,0.36383198969179
"bar2",-1.35613767310069,-0.124014006180608
```

Any of these help?

EDIT: Added the `index_label=False` option today which does what you want:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
       A  B
one    1  4
two    2  5
three  3  6

In [3]: df.to_csv('foo.csv', index_
index_exp     index_label=  index_name=   

In [3]: df.to_csv('foo.csv', index_name=False)

In [4]: 
11:24 ~/code/pandas  (master)$ R

R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)
Copyright (C) 2011 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

re> read.csv('foo.csv')
      A B
one   1 4
two   2 5
three 3 6
```

Comment: Alas, that preceding comma also causes R to interpret the rownames as integers, placing the true row names as entries in the first column. My solution was to write script in R that saves the first column of the incoming Frame object, removes it, and assigned its values to the rownames. It's a bit clunky, but it works. I'm just confused because in the documentation (help(B_p.to_csv)) it doesn't show anything in the upper-left-hand corner when you pivot a table. I suspect this is some sort of left-over from the introduction of MultiIndexing, which I'll admit I don't understand thoroughly.

Comment: I'll see about adding an option to the to_csv function in a future release