# Comparing two lines in csv file - Python

Tags: python, linux, csv, numpy

I am trying to compare two rows in a csv. 
For example:

```
abc, 2, foo, bar, baz
abc, 2, bar,baz, band
cab, 3, baz,bar, foo
cab, 3, baz,bar, foo
```

Is there way `csv` module or any module in python to check if the column 1 is same or different.

For example:
in the first two lines, we see `2` and in the third line we see the number `3`. is there a way to find that out

The idea behind it is to sum the values corresponding to a particular value in `column 1`

so,

```
abc, 2, 10,11,12
abc, 2, 7,8,9
cab, 3, 4,5,6
cab, 3, 1,2,3
```

I essentially want to sum up the values `12+9` for since it has the same column 1.
and numbers `6 and 3` since the value 3 is same in column 1

To sum it up I am assuming I can create a list with

```
a=list()
```

append the value to that list

```
a.append(float(line[4]))
```

and use numpy to sum it up

```
numpy.sum(a)
```

Could any one please help me figure out a pythonic way to find if the two values are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
with open('abc') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',', skipinitialspace = True)
    for row in reader:
        c[row[1]] += int(row[-1])
...         
>>> c
Counter({'2': 21, '3': 9})
```

To find the columns use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> with open('abc') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',', skipinitialspace = True)
    for k,g in groupby(enumerate(reader), key = lambda x:x[1][1]):
        print k," was common on the rows :",",".join(str(x[0]) for x in g)
...         
2  was common on the rows : 0,1
3  was common on the rows : 2,3
```

Comment: Is it not possible for say something like this.

`for line in reader:`
  `for row in line:`
    `print row`

Comment: @pistal I am iterating over each row only.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library, you can easily aggregate columns based on groups. For example if you have a csv like:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
abc,2,10,11,12
abc,2,7,8,9
cab,3,4,5,6
cab,3,1,2,3
```

You can group and sum based on the values in `col2` with just a couple of lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('test.csv')
df.groupby('col2').sum()
```

Which gives you:

```
      col3  col4  col5
col2                  
2       17    19    21
3        5     7     9
```

Comment: I am trying to write it to a csv file using the help of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105728/pivoting-a-dataframe-in-pandas-for-output-to-csv`
Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use python group by function
http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

```
from itertools import groupby
grouped = groupby(data, lambda x: x[1])
```

this will give you data grouped by the second column.
Then you can get sum for each key by:

```
for key, values in grouped:
    columnSum = sum(map(lambda x: int(x[4]), values))
```